# Scroll entire list View horizontally

Tags: android

I have a custom list view which contains 14 fields.Something like this:

field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9 field10 field11 field12 field13 field14.
Now the obvious problem is that is no possible way i can fit all the fields on the screen,so i would like to make the entire list view scroll horizontally,so i could display only   5-6 fields,and when the user scrolls  horizontally he will be able to see the rest of them.
I is possible to have a list view that scrolls both vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

simply create list view inside the horizontal scroll view, skeleton as follows

```
<HorizontalScrollView ...........>
    <LinearLayout ......>
        <LinearLayout ......>
        //List View Titles will be here
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView ........ android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here, If you need to show non-scroll-able title to list view then add it in separate layout as like mentioned and don't forget to set **layout_weight** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a HorizontalScrollView that should be the child of a VerticalScrollView as given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362460/how-can-we-make-table-layout-to-scroll-both-ways-horizontally-vertically).

Answer (score 0):

simplest and easy way to implement horizontal listview.

**Horizonatalscroll.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:background="@color/list_item_bg_color">

 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**horizontal_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/horizontal_outer_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/rect_border_box"
android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
   </Linearlayout>
```

**java code:**

```
      LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.observation_detail_parent_layout, null);
      Linearlayout child= null;


     //iterate views upto you adapater count.
      for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
      child = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.horizontal_list, null);

        //set your views specified in horizontal_list.xml

      TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
      text.setText("your text");
      parent.addView(child);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

List View already supports vertical scrolling, so we need to support horizontal scrolling.Below code worked perfectly fine for me.
Be careful, do not keep "height as 0dp" for list view even if "weight is 1".Because HorizontalScrollView will take the height as zero and will not draw any item for the list view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/table_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="header"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mylist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ListView>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```