# Horizontal list view Scrollable in Xamarin Android?

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, horizontal-scrolling

I have a screen where, in the bottom I have to make a horizontal list view which is selectable. Each time when ,I click on the list view, Respective row element details will come in the Upper Part of screen?? and the selected, List row changes its background color. How can I achieve this?? I am working on Xamarin.Droid and need a Hellp??

Answer (score 0):

maybe this gonna help you!!

all that you have to do is to create a list view inside horizontal scroll view

[Scroll entire list View horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699566/scroll-entire-list-view-horizontally)

Comment: I have used <horizontal list view> 
<ListView> 
 <RelativeLAyout>
........
</RelativeLAyout>
 </ListView> 
</horizontal list view>
But its not scrolling horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a screen where, in the bottom I have to make a horizontal list view which is selectable. Each time when ,I click on the list view, Respective row element details will come in the Upper Part of screen??

The best practise is to use `RecyclerView` as google recommended, and with `LinearLayoutManager`, items can be shown vertically or horizontally.

For details of implementing a recyclerView, please refer to [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/recycler-view/).

Comment: For some Reason I am not able to work on Recycler view, I have to implement Horizontal list view only.

Comment: Then you have to either create your own custom listview or using a third party lib for that. There is no easy way to accomplish that.

Comment: You can refer to  [Paul Soucy's HorizontalListView.java](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java) and cheesebaron's C# [implementation of that](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.HorizontalListView).